# jQuery fade not Animating Smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm using jQuery fade on .hover to hide an element, and make it reappear on mouseexit, but when I run the .fadeOut() method, regardless of the duration I enter, or if I leave it to the default, it waits the duration then (dis)appears instantly rather than slowly fading out/in over the duration.  I'm on the latest version of chrome.  Anyone else run into this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbutton").hover(
        function() {
            $('span.linktext, span.linkdropcap').fadeOut();
        },
        function() {
            $('span.linktext, span.linkdropcap').fadeIn();
        }
    );
});
```

Other browsers are giving me the exact same behavior.

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TXrDk/

Comment: I recently took on a project that used a lot of animations, and noticed a lot of issues in chrome with these types of animations. Surprisingly enough, Firefox and IE had no problems.  What kind of experience are you getting with those two browsers?

Comment: Can you post an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Working fine here in firefox

Comment: Sorry, didn't read question fully. I've had this issue on Chrome as well. You can try doing a manual `$('span').animate({opacity:0},600)` fade, this has helped mine before.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take this out of the elements you want to fade, and it works fine. example:   [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXrDk/2/)

```
transition:.5s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Good to know that CSS transition parameters break jQuery animations.

Comment: I've been having the hardest time with a customer's website and the jQuery transitions not being smooth. This entire time it was because the last developer put `*{transition: all .2s;}`.

Comment: holy cow, that´s it, that´s why my fade effects were not smooth too, omg thank you very much